# I need to animate the change the 3 letters with the items of an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, random

[image: Example Element]
I need to animate the change of these 3 characters with the data of the array, when I click this blue button on the right.

This is the HTML code I have written so far.

```
<div class="cards">
    <div id="card1" class="card">L</div>
    <div id="card2" class="card">A</div>
    <div id="card3" class="card">X</div>
    <a class="btn btn-flat shuffle" href="#" onclick="travelSurprise();"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript code is here.

```
function travelSurprise() {
    let cities = ["NYC", "PTH", "SDN", "KTY", "PRT"];
    let card1 = document.getElementById("card1");
    let card2 = document.getElementById("card2");
    let card3 = document.getElementById("card3");

    for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        setInterval(function shuffle() {
            card1.innerHTML = cities[i].charAt(0);
            card2.innerHTML = cities[i].charAt(1);
            card3.innerHTML = cities[i].charAt(2);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

I need to change these three letters when I click the button. Animation should be like the 3 letters will change to all the elements of the array for 3,4 seconds and stop at a random position.

Comment: question is unclear

Comment: @Artur I have changed the question. I need to change these three letters when I click the button. Animation should be like the 3 letters will change to all the elements of the array and stop at a random position. Thanks.

Comment: At random time or specific time? (the full animation time)

Comment: @Artur Animate for 3,4 seconds and sop at a random value. Thanks

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/text/Airport-Like-Text-Flip-Animation-with-jQuery-CSS3-splitFlap.html this does what you want.

Comment: @callback indeed that's what I needed. Apparently I need to do this with pure JavaScript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setTimeout()` instead, where the second argument is the `500ms` time multiplied by an index of every array item. For the shuffle, use Fisher-Yates algorithm [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) and just do it every time the `a` is clicked.

```js
  

function shuffle(array) {
  // shuffle your array code
  return array;
}

function travelSurprise(event) {
    
    let cities = ["NYC", "PTH", "SDN", "KTY", "PRT"];
    let card1 = document.getElementById("card1");
    let card2 = document.getElementById("card2");
    let card3 = document.getElementById("card3");
    
    shuffle(cities);

    cities.forEach((city, index) => {
    
      setTimeout(() => {
        
        card1.innerHTML = city.charAt(0);
        card1.innerHTML = city.charAt(1);
        card2.innerHTML = city.charAt(2);
        
  
      }, (index * 500));
    
    });
}
```

```css
.cards > div {
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: .3rem;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <div id="card1" class="card">L</div>
    <div id="card2" class="card">A</div>
    <div id="card3" class="card">X</div>
    <a class="btn btn-flat shuffle" href="#" onclick="travelSurprise();"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: It works exactly as I needed. Thanks @wscourge . Is there any way that I can stop the animation in a random position.

Comment: Read an edit and follow the link, as shuffling the array is the whole different story. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @wscourge. Works fine.